# Pass parameter to report c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, report

I have an error when I try to pass a parameter to my report.

An unhandled exception of type 'Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalProcessingException' occurred in Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll.

My code:

```
ReportViewer reportViwer = new ReportViewer();
reportViwer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;

reportViwer.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "MyReport.Report1.rdlc";

List<ReportParameter> listReportParameter = new List<ReportParameter>();

listReportParameter.Add(new ReportParameter("Name", "Test"));

reportViwer.LocalReport.SetParameters(listReportParameter);
```

The error is in "SetParameters".

The description:

```
Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalProcessingException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=An error occurred during local report processing.
  Source=Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalReport.CompileReport()
       at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalReport.SetParameters(IEnumerable`1 parameters)
       at MyReport.Form1.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in e:\_Organizado\AERON\Projetos\Visual Studio C#\Relatorio\MyReport\Form1.cs:line 37
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
       at MyReport.Program.Main() in e:\_Organizado\AERON\Projetos\Visual Studio C#\Relatorio\MyReport\Program.cs:line 19
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: Microsoft.Reporting.DefinitionInvalidException
       HResult=-2146233088
       Message=The definition of the report 'Main Report' is invalid.
       Source=Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common
       ExceptionLevelHelpLink=http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=20476&EvtSrc=Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ErrorStrings&EvtID=pvInvalidDefinition&ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server%20Reporting%20Services&ProdVer=9.0.21022.8
       SkipTopLevelMessage=false
       StackTrace:
            at Microsoft.Reporting.ReportCompiler.CompileReport(CatalogItemContext context, Byte[] reportDefinition, Boolean generateExpressionHostWithRefusedPermissions, ReportSnapshotBase& snapshot)
            at Microsoft.Reporting.StandalonePreviewStore.StoredReport.CompileReport()
            at Microsoft.Reporting.StandalonePreviewStore.StoredReport.get_Snapshot()
            at Microsoft.Reporting.StandalonePreviewStore.GetCompiledReport(CatalogItemContext context, Boolean rebuild, ReportSnapshotBase& snapshot)
            at Microsoft.Reporting.LocalService.CompileReport(CatalogItemContext itemContext, Boolean rebuild)
            at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalReport.CompileReport()
       InnerException: Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException
            HResult=-2146233088
            Message=The report definition is not valid.  Details: The report definition has an invalid target namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition' which cannot be upgraded.
            Source=Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common
            ExceptionLevelHelpLink=http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=20476&EvtSrc=Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ErrorStrings&EvtID=rsProcessingError&ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server%20Reporting%20Services&ProdVer=9.0.21022.8
            SkipTopLevelMessage=false
            StackTrace:
                 at Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportPublishing.Phase1(CatalogItemContext reportContext, Byte[] definition, CreateReportChunk createChunkCallback, CheckSharedDataSource checkDataSourceCallback, String& description, String& language, DataSourceInfoCollection& dataSources, UserLocationFlags& userReferenceLocation, Boolean& hasExternalImages, Boolean& hasHyperlinks)
                 at Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportPublishing.CreateIntermediateFormat(CatalogItemContext reportContext, Byte[] definition, CreateReportChunk createChunkCallback, CheckSharedDataSource checkDataSourceCallback, PublishingErrorContext errorContext, AppDomain compilationTempAppDomain, Boolean generateExpressionHostWithRefusedPermissions, String& description, String& language, ParameterInfoCollection& parameters, DataSourceInfoCollection& dataSources, UserLocationFlags& userReferenceLocation, ArrayList& dataSetsName, Boolean& hasExternalImages, Boolean& hasHyperlinks)
                 at Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessing.CompileReport(CatalogItemContext reportContext, Byte[] reportDefinition, CreateReportChunk createChunkCallback, CheckSharedDataSource checkDataSourceCallback, PublishingErrorContext errorContext, AppDomain compilationTempAppDomain, Boolean generateExpressionHostWithRefusedPermissions, String& reportDescription, String& reportLanguage, ParameterInfoCollection& parameters, DataSourceInfoCollection& dataSources, UserLocationFlags& userReferenceLocation, ArrayList& dataSetsName, Boolean& hasExternalImages, Boolean& hasHyperlinks)
                 at Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessing.CreateIntermediateFormat(CatalogItemContext reportContext, Byte[] reportDefinition, CreateReportChunk createChunkCallback, CheckSharedDataSource checkDataSourceCallback, AppDomain compilationTempAppDomain, Boolean generateExpressionHostWithRefusedPermissions)
                 at Microsoft.Reporting.ReportCompiler.CompileReport(CatalogItemContext context, Byte[] reportDefinition, Boolean generateExpressionHostWithRefusedPermissions, ReportSnapshotBase& snapshot)
            InnerException:
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: See this [thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/47ecd315-6372-46cf-b319-df098334fc74/the-report-definition-has-an-invalid-target-namespace?forum=vsreportcontrols), hopefully it helps

Comment: I'm using Visual 2013, and  The top of my file is: <Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <UsingTask TaskName="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlCompile" AssemblyName="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"/>

Answer (score 0):

Add the parameters with names "Name" and "Test" in your report and try again.

If it has already been done, try changing

```
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "MyReport.Report1.rdlc";
```

To:

```
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "MyReport.Report1.rdlc";
```

You can also try this: `Uncheck` the `Internal` property of the "Name" parameter.

Check the properties of your parameters in the report. (Right click on the report pane, select Parameters.)

`UNCHECK`    -`internal`-

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.

Was happening in my report because I had placed two parameters in testings, and I was just passing the data to one of them.

In my report were created the "Name" and "Test" parameters, and I was just passing the value for "Name".

```
listReportParameter.Add (new ReportParameter ("Name", this.textBox1.Text));
```

When I deleted  the "Test" parameter in the report it worked.

Thanks